# Is it possible to make a single entity perform multiple animations?

Tags: animation, aframe

I want to know if I can make one object, like a box or sphere, do 2 animations, as in rotation and color.
I know you can set these in the property section of the animation attribute, but if I try to put multiple animation attributes on one object, or if I try to put 2 properties in 1 animation attribute, it either doesn't animate, or only does one of the animations.
Here is the code I'm using, I would appreciate if any of you could edit it to make it work, if this is possible:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.0.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a-scene>
        <a-sky color="lightblue"></a-sky>
        <a-box position="0 0 -5" width="2" depth="2" height="2" color= rgb(0,0,0)
        animation="
        property: rotation;
        from: 0 0 0;
        to: -360 -360 -360;
        loop: true;
        dur: 3000;
        dir: alternate;
        property: color;
        from: rgb(0,0,0);
        to: rgb(255,255,255);
        loop: true;
        dur: 3000;
        dir: alternate;"></a-box>
        </a-scene>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to split the animation instructions into [separate `animation` components](https://aframe.io/docs/1.2.0/components/animation.html#multiple-animations), which should look like this:

```
animation__<id>="stuff"
// like this:
animation__first="single animation related stuff"
animation__second="another single animation related stuff"
```

your code should look a bit more like this:

```html
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.2.0/aframe.min.js"></script>

<a-scene>
  <a-sky color="lightblue"></a-sky>
  <a-box position="0 0 -5" width="2" depth="2" height="2" color=rgb(0,0,0) 
  
        animation__rotation="
        property: rotation;
        from: 0 0 0;
        to: -360 -360 -360;
        loop: true;
        dur: 3000;
        dir: alternate;"
        
        animation__color="
        property: color;
        from: rgb(0,0,0);
        to: rgb(255,255,255);
        loop: true;
        dur: 3000;
        dir: alternate;"></a-box>
</a-scene>
```